# How to stub Winston logger with sinon

Tags: node.js, sinon, winston

I have a logger which utilizes the Winston NodeJs package. The logger does additional logic, and I would like to have unit tests to ensure that the proper data is being passed to Winston. However, since I have  set up external transports (such as Firehose) I do not need those to be invoked.

I am not passing in Winston as a dependency through the constructor, but I have tried stubbing the `createLogger` method, the `log` method, and Winston as a whole as I normally would when stubbing a dependency.

The `createStubbedInstance` method does not work with Winston (or, I have not been able to get it to work) due to the fact that Winston is not exported as a class, but as a namespace.

```
import { Logger, ILoggerConfig } from './src';
import * as winston from 'winston'
describe('Logger', () => {
  let loggerConfig: ILoggerConfig;
  let sandbox: sinon.SinonSandbox;
  beforeEach(() => {
    sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();

    loggerConfig = {
      correlationId: faker.random.uuid(),
      action: 'GET',
    };
    sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
    winstonStub = sandbox.stub(winston);
    winstonStub.createLogger.resolves();
    winstonStub.log.resolves();
    ...
  });

  it('should log with INFO log level', () => {
    const logger = new Logger(loggerConfig);
    logger.info('Hello there!');

    sinon.assert.calledOnce(winstonStub.log);
    sinon.assert.calledWith(winsonStub.log, sinon.match.has("level", 'info'))
  });
```

```
import { Logger, ILoggerConfig } from './src';
import * as winston from 'winston'
describe('Logger', () => {
  let loggerConfig: ILoggerConfig;
  let sandbox: sinon.SinonSandbox;
  beforeEach(() => {
    sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();

    loggerConfig = {
      correlationId: faker.random.uuid(),
      action: 'GET',
    };
    sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
    winstonStub = sandbox.stub(winston, 'createLogger').resolves({ log: sanbox.stub() });
    ...
  });

  it('should log with INFO log level', () => {
    const logger = new Logger(loggerConfig);
    logger.info('Hello there!');

    sinon.assert.calledOnce(winstonStub);
  });
```

I would expect to be able to assert that the stub would be called a certain number of times. However, the stub always has a call count of 0, and I get an error indicating that Winston cannot post to Firehose due to permission issues. I also have the Console transport set up, and still see logs in the console when I should not.

Comment: Could you post a little bit of codebase which you are trying to test? Basically, if you `require()` your class, which `require`s your logger, at the top of the test file then stubbing anything in the logger does not do anything because it's already imported in the base class, and your stub does not affect it. You need to either stub the logger before importing the base class or inject the logger in the constructor of the base class and then test it. Does it make sense to you?

Comment: Yes. I am writing unit tests for the logger itself.

I'll update with a little bit more code to show what my tests look like

Comment: For anyone coming to this in the future. I figured it out. Oddly enough, the syntax `import * as winston from 'winston'` is readonly. I altered it to `import winston from 'winston'` in both my test file and application file and was able to successfully stub out the properties I needed to.

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't use `"esModuleInterop": true` with `import winston from 'winston'` due to strict settings of the project causing a ripple effect of compilation issues.

Luckily I found a clean way to mock what I needed when mocking `log` directly failed.

```
import * as tape from "tape";
import * as sinon from "sinon";
import * as winston from "winston";

tape('Stubbing winston', (test) => {
  test.test('Or at least part of it', (test) => {

    const logSpy = sinon.spy()

    sinon
      .stub(winston, "createLogger")
      .callsFake(() => ({
        log: logSpy,
      } as unknown as Logger));

    const logger = new MyLoggerThatUsesWinston()
    logger.log('Only lost');
    logger.log('four hours');
    logger.log('on this');

    test.equal(logSpy.callCount, 3, "")
    test.end();
  }
  test.end();
}
```

Comment: Love the log messages :)